# In c# how do I set the active directy field "office" so i can show the location of our users in Outlook

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

In c# I'm trying to set the office field

[image]

When I do this:

ADEntry.Properties[ "office"].Add( "Alaska");

It says office does not exist.

Can anyone tell me where to get at this property?

Thanks,

Cal-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Richard Mueller's web site](http://www.rlmueller.net/UserAttributes.htm) - he has tons of reference Excel sheets on what property in the AD UI maps to what underlying AD property on `DirectoryEntry`.

Your concrete "office" example maps to a property called `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` in the `DirectoryEntry`'s `.Properties` collection....

Comment: Thanks! Your powers are Mighty!

Answer (score 7):

After long research I got it..

```
string Username = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Substring(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);

 string office = string.Empty;

    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DOMAIN"].ToString()))
    {
        using (var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(context))
        {
            userPrincipal.SamAccountName = Username;

            using (PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal))
            {
                UserPrincipal result = (UserPrincipal)search.FindOne();

                DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

                if (directoryEntry.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"].Count > 0
                        && directoryEntry.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"][0] != null
                        && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(directoryEntry.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"][0].ToString()))
                {
                    office = directoryEntry.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"][0].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```